# Working with python 'ipaddress' and the purpose of _methods versus direct values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm hoping to get some clarification here(New to python). So I'm trying to call out a large VLAN, then break that VLAN into a few smaller subnets based on some criteria.

In looking at all the class methods I see a method called `_prefixlen`. Looking at other posts in stackoverflow, it looks like generally the _methods are generally private module methods, and are not brought in when calling `import`. [Source here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name). However, using this method it does allow me to change the prefixlen.

```
import ipaddress as ip
network1 = ip.ip_network(network_allocation)
network1._prefixlen = 10
print(network1.prefixlen)
>>> 10
```

Is this a normal convention, or did I just confused by a normal convention, any guidance would be really helpful.

Comment: I can't find that example code in the current docs?

Comment: @snakecharmerb good call, I linked the wrong doc page, editing my link above.

Comment: `netaddr` is a third party package that you need to [install](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), its `IPAddress` class is not the same as that in the stdlib.

Comment: @snakecharmerb ah, that makes way more sense.

Comment: Modified my question to be focused on the _method versus the syntax component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a single and a double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Comment: You aren't supposed to change the prefix length; it's an immutable property of the network that `network1` represents. If you have a different prefix length, you have a different network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is truly "private" in Python; the saying goes that "it's cultural."  Something prefixed with a single underscore is "quasi-private" in that it's the developer's way of saying, "you shouldn't really need to touch this." (Or maybe, that if you rely on this in application code, it's subject to change with zero notice.)

The [pattern](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9d7b2c0909b78800d1376fd696f73824ea680463/Lib/ipaddress.py#L733) the question seems to be getting at looks like this:

```
@property
def prefixlen(self):
    return self._prefixlen
```

Where:

- `_prefixlen` is an **attribute**
- `prefixlen` is a **property** - basically an instance method that you don't need to call with `()`, to oversimplify things

In this case, this effectively makes `prefixlen` readonly, though the underlying attribute `_prefixlen` is perfectly modifiable if you really want to:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> nw = ipaddress.ip_network('192.0.2.0/24')
>>> nw.prefixlen
24
>>> nw.prefixlen = 32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

If you want to modify the prefix, you might as well create a new object -- Adding a `@property.setter` that modifies the given object inplace would fundamentally change what you're looking at, so `IPv4Network` and `IPv6Network` instances are best treated as being immutable.

One nice trick is that the class constructors [accept a tuple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9d7b2c0909b78800d1376fd696f73824ea680463/Lib/ipaddress.py#L1514) for the `address` parameter, so you can construct from parts:

```
>>> ipaddress.IPv4Network((nw.network_address, 32))
IPv4Network('192.0.2.0/32')
```

Thanks to @chepner for this last trick from his comments below.

Comment: There's no setter because the length of a prefix isn't *supposed* to be changed. `192.0.2.0/24` and `192.0.2.0/26`, for example, are two different prefixes.

Comment: Instances of `IPv4Network` (and other similar classes in the module) are immutable in spirt, if not in fact. If you have `192.0.2.0/24` and want `192.0.2.0/26`, you get a new instance with `IPv4Network((nw.network_address, 26))`.

Comment: "you shouldn't really need to touch this." I'd say "unless we know each other personally, don't expect a warning if I get rid of this method in the future"

Comment: Super helpful guys. I think some of my confusion is coming from understanding of methods, attributes, properties and the like. I'll go dive into this more.